# Trying to send Serial command upon mouse click, 90% there

Tags: cmd, serial-port, mouseevent, mousewheel

I am trying to send a Hex command from the P.C's serial port. So far I am doing this with a batch script using a modification of this code and the "copy" function.

```
@echo off
echo BEEF100500C6FF111101000100>off.txt
echo BEEF030600DCDB690000000000>on.txt

certutil -decodehex off.txt off.bin
certutil -decodehex on.txt on.bin

MODE COM1:19,n,8,1
copy off.bin \\.\com1 /b
copy on.bin \\.\com1 /b
```

What I would like to do is send the Hex command any time the mouse wheel is scrolled up, or send a different command any time the mouse wheel is scrolled down.

The missing piece for me is how to read the input from the USB optical mouse, and combine this event with my desired function.

I found this link on Microsofts help page, but I do not understand all of it and I'm not sure how to incorporate this as my solution.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/mouse-input

Open to any solutions except that I'd like to avoid using third part software like AutoHotKey. Any opensource code or executable are O.K.

Comment: I have found this, Which moves a text box up and down, I would need to just modify it to execute my code to send the hex command, easy enough. Except I can't get the example to run. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mousewheeleventargs.delta?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Input_MouseWheelEventArgs_Delta

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to do that, but you may wish to adapt the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37184313/10553001) for your needs.

Comment: Thank you Steve. I will give this a try integrating the batch mouse click detection but it looks like just what i needed.

Comment: I've played around with the answer provided by Steve. But am having trouble modifying the code to act upon the mouse wheel. I changed line " MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)" to " MouseMessages.WM_MOUSEWHEEL == (MouseMessages)wParam) " So now it acts on Mouse wheel rotation. But what I really need is for it to return whether the mouse wheel was rotated up or down. I looked through this here, http://www.andreavb.com/tip060007.html and this here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-mousewheel But I am inexperienced and can't exactly make sense of it?

Comment: Any ideas how to incorporate this or how I can learn what everything on this page means? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-mousewheel

Comment: It looks like you look at the sign of the value of wParam, which indicates whether the wheel was rotated forward/up (positive) or backward/down (negative). Sample code is in the link you provided.